# Can jQuery be used to select a div based on its height? Or is the tutorial wrong?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I am trying to select a `div` based on its height, as shown in this tutorial,
[jQuery Selection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jquery/selection.html). I cannot get it to work: [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/eriqix/1/edit) . The line not working is:

```
   $('div[height=50px]').css('background-color', 'orange');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector, so the HTML it would match is:

```
<div height="50px"></div>
```

You could change it to:

```
$('div[style="height:50px"]').css('background-color', 'orange');
```

According to comments, the above doesn't work in Internet Explorer. Try the following instead:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('height') == '50px';
}).css('background-color', 'orange');
```

If you want to match other elements with a height of 50px not specified using an attribute, take a look at the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function.

Comment: $('div[style="height:50px"]').css('background-color', 'orange');  works well.  I tried many permutations but not that one.  Thanks.

Comment: $('div[style="height:50px"]').css('background-color', 'orange'); doesn't work in IE.  Works in Chrome.

Comment: @soupman55 Edited the answer to include another method using `.filter()` to select the elements.

Comment: Thanks. Your code with filter function works well in Chrome & IE   http://jsbin.com/eriqix/9/

Comment: This code does not work for me.  If I change the style of the element to height:50;background-color:orange, it no longer gets picked up by selector, unless I change it back to just "height:50".

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is...

```
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
```

Then your selector should be...

```
$('div[style*="height:50px"]');
```

If you are setting height to the value of "50px" and " 50px" (common), you will need to adjust accordingly...

```
$('div[style*="height:50px"], div[style*="height: 50px"]');
```

If you change the CSS of this element, the div's style attribute might become: "height:50px;background-color:orange", and it would cease to get picked up by this selector.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/