# Select content on left

Tags: jquery, css, position

Bit of a weird question.

Is there any way to select (either via jQuery, JS or CSS) divs which are on the left within a container?

I'm working on a site here http://goo.gl/2NlTH which has the divs set in masonry so there's not an odd, even or every X number of divs using nth-child as the divs that are on the left change based on the content height. I need to select the divs are on touching the left hand side of the container to change their widths and padding appropriately to fit the layout.

Cheers... sorry for the convoluted question - hopefully the site helps.

-R

Comment: I hope this post can help..
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741029/can-jquery-be-used-to-select-a-div-based-on-its-height-or-is-the-tutorial-wrong>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible!

here is the selector code for jquery :

```
$('.masonry-brick[style*="left: 0px"]');
```

this selecting masonry divs on the left. and you can do whatever you want to them like this:

```
$('.masonry-brick[style*="left: 0px"]').css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This has helped a lot.

Comment: Trust me, this is not correct. This will only work when the `style` attribute is there, that is inline-css, which is generally frowned upon as a bad practice. And even if you do go by this method, instead of doing it the harder way, why not just assign a class to these elements, say `leftie`, and use that style?

Comment: He is using jquery-masonry. I don't even no have you ever tried it. He already posted a link developed with this plugin and he wanted help about that plugin. I know, it'll not work on other projects if there is no left property but masonry using left property and absolute positioning. So, I know, what I do. Don't confuse people.

Comment: ^^ What he said. The only issue is it'll have to apply the changes to these elements once masonry runs, but then the height of the elements change... can I callback masonry?

Comment: I am not confusing him. Apply some common sense, if he really wants to choose those elements with a `left` attribute with value `ox`, why do it with `$('.masonry-brick[style*="left: 0px"]')` when he can do it with `$(".leftie")`?

Comment: And for your information, you answer is wrong. `$('.masonry-brick[style*="left: 0px"]')` will also choose elements where the `left` attribute is not `0px`, but the `margin-left` attribute is `0px`. It should be `$('.masonry-brick[style~="left: 0px"]')`. Looks like you still have way to go before you know what you do.

Comment: You can't do leftie because nobody knows which one will be the left. masonry plugin repositioning divs after html render. and it's fully dynamic. I mean page is not static. If you change content, div's order will changed too.

@Richard what do you want to do I don't understand. Can you explain it more simple or detailed?

Comment: 1. Masonry called 2. jQuery you gave me looks for elements with elements with their left position 0 as the Masonry gave it as changes the width and padding 3. These elements with the new styles therefore need to be ran through masonry again as now these overlap. Look at the link I gave for the output. Therefore, once these new styles have been applied, masonry needs to rerun. Any ideas?

Comment: i looked to your website. i think you need this code because you made something wrong on your css. if you give "float: left" property to article element which one is under the grid_3 events-landing-rest, you will not need to change height things. it'll automatically set it.

Comment: It's because the jQuery we're adding to the left:0 elements is fired after the masonry.

Answer (score -2):

**On the left** is an abstract notion, CSS has no way of identifying that. You can assign all those elements a certain class, and apply the CSS on that class.

Comment: But how can I assign a class to those elements if they're dynamically given a location? I realise 'on the left' is an abstract notion, but I was thinking of DOM position? Every div that's left:0 in the container or similar...

Comment: All these divs have a style position of left:0 so perhaps I can select them using this? cc/ @Stev

Comment: No, that is not possible. You have to think of other methods.